# Should I use Session State or SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, session

I am building a forum, and i need to set all the threads by their topics and then by their topic number. I could do this programmatically or with t-sql.

Programmatically, I will have to save a dictionary of page number and topics in a session state. I dont know how it effects performance. And with t-SQL, I will have to use some logic and then assign a page number to the thread.. In terms of performance, which one is better?

Comment: its not exactly clear what you want to do. Do you have a list of topics that you want to page (or its a list of topic with threads underneath (expanded view) that you want to page)?

Comment: umm - programmatically OR t-sql?? I know T-SQL has it's issues but referring to it as a not-programmatic process is a little harsh!

Comment: I want to list threads by their page numbers... after they were classified by topics... as i said before

Comment: not quite sure why you would want to store this in sessions state, isnt that per user, check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't real clear, but it sounds like if you want to read everything in, process it, and cache it for performance, you should use the Application cache which applies to all users, not the Session cache which only applies to the current user. If you used the Session cache every user would have the same data — unless you're caching the data that is sorted or unique to a particular user. (Your question wasn't clear what your purpose is.)

Generally you should use the SQL approach if there would be a lot of unnecessary data going back and forth, having to run multiple queries, etc. when all you need is the summarized, final version sent to the web tier. What "a lot" is depends on many factors, none of which were included in your Question.

Without any more context, all we can say is profile both to see which is faster.

Answer (score -2):

In-process session state vanishes whenever your IIS worker process recycles. That is typically at least once a day.  So for a forum, session state isn't an option at all.

Comment: But i do have a code that regenerates the all the objects needed and put them into a session state , again and again.. so whats the problem?